# Aspnet Core Select action by complex parameter in the body

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I wrote an API in Aspnet Core 1.1, but one of the requirement is every request must be a post request to a single route and depending of the type in body payload load one action, I tried inheriting `ActionMethodSelectorAttribute` and implement `IsValidForRequest` then decorate every Action passing the type expected this is a simple approach, and it works but the problem comes in when I try to use  `RouteContext.HttpContext.Request.Body` it is an Stream object, and if I try to deserialize it more than once it throws and exception and also I used cache, that helped me to avoid the exception, but as soon the Action is selected the body has already consume and is not possible to use for serialize it again and be used for the model binder.

```
public override bool IsValidForRequest(RouteContext routeContext, ActionDescriptor action)
{

    try
    {
        var body = new MemoryStream();
        routeContext.HttpContext.Request.Body.CopyTo(body);

        body.Position = 0;

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        var xml = XDocument.Load(body);
        var messageName = xml.Root.Name.LocalName;
        return messageName == _messageType.Name;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }

}

[MessagBasedControllerActionSelector(typeof(OTA_HotelInvCountRQ))]
public async Task<IActionResult> OTA_HotelInvCount([FromBody]OTA_HotelInvCountRQ request)
{
    var response = await _otaService.OTA_HotelInvCountRQ(request, GetExternalProviderId());
    return Ok(response);
}
```

I know this approach doesn't scale, and I'd be happy to listen another solution or one that meets my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I get this working, the key point is a method call to `routeContext.HttpContext.Request.EnableRewind()` it allow reuse the body stream by put its `position = 0`

I used Memory cache to mitigate the overhead.

Here my solution

```
 public class MessagBasedControllerActionSelectorAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
    {
        private const string RequestHashCodeKey = "RequestHashCodeKey";
        private const string MessageRootNameKey = "MessageRootNameKey";
        private readonly string _messageTypeName;
        private ICacheService _cache;

        public MessagBasedControllerActionSelectorAttribute(string messageTypeName)
        {
            _messageTypeName = messageTypeName;
        }

        public override bool IsValidForRequest(RouteContext routeContext, ActionDescriptor action)
        {
            //Get reference to cache from DI container
            _cache = routeContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(ICacheService)) as ICacheService;

            //Get Request hashCode from cache if is possible
            var existingRequestHash = _cache.Get<string>(RequestHashCodeKey);
            var req = routeContext.HttpContext.Request;
            var messageName = string.Empty;
            int.TryParse(existingRequestHash, out int cacheRequestHash);

            //Verify if the incoming request is the same that has been cached before or deserialize the body in case new request
            if (cacheRequestHash != req.GetHashCode())
            {
                //store new request hash code
                _cache.Store(RequestHashCodeKey, req.GetHashCode().ToString());
                //enable to rewind the body stream this allows then put position 0 and let the model binder serialize again
                req.EnableRewind();
                var xmlBody = "";
                req.Body.Position = 0;

                //Read XML
                using (StreamReader reader
                    = new StreamReader(req.Body, Encoding.UTF8, true, 1024, true))
                {
                    xmlBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }


                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                var xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlBody);
                //Get the root name
                messageName = xml.Root.Name.LocalName;
                //Store the root name in cache
                _cache.Store(MessageRootNameKey, messageName);

                req.Body.Position = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                //Get root name from cache
                messageName = _cache.Get<string>(MessageRootNameKey);
            }

            return messageName == _messageTypeName;
        }
    }
```

And in the controller use it like this:

```
 [MessagBasedControllerActionSelector(nameof(My_Request_Type))]
        public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction([FromBody]My_Request_Typerequest)
        {
            //Some cool stuff
            return Ok(response);
        }
```